# How to run `go test` in the parent directory of multiple go modules and return non-zero in case of error

Tags: go, go-testing

Take a look at this directory structure:

```
/root
    /hoge
        go.mod
        go.sum
        main.go
        /test
           main_test.go
           /unit
              sub_test.go
    /fuga
        go.mod
        go.sum
        main.go
        /test
           main_test.go
```

You can run the test with the following code, but if it fails, it will always return an exit code of 0.

```
find . -name go.mod -execdir go test ./... \;
```

Is there any way to return non-zero if it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command:

```
find . -name go.mod -execdir go test ./... -- {} +
```

Manual for the `find` command about `-execdir command {} +`:

> If any invocation with the `+' form returns a non-zero value as exit status, then find returns a non-zero exit status. If find encounters an error, this can sometimes cause an immediate exit, so some pending commands may not be run at all.

But `go test` don't need the matched file from the `find` command. In fact, it will fail like this:

```
$ go test ./... go.mod
no required module provides package go.mod; to add it:
    go get go.mod
```

It failed because `go.mod` is interpreted as a package.

The workaround is to add the terminator `--` before `{} +`. See [Command line flag syntax](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#hdr-Command_line_flag_syntax):

> Flag parsing stops just before the first non-flag argument ("-" is a non-flag argument) or after the terminator "--".